# how to Fit QGraphicsScene in a QGraphicsView

Tags: qt4

I want to to fit a `QGraphicsScene` in a `QGraphicsView` with different dimensions, such that it will shrink or expand according to size of view, and there should be no any scrollbar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt GraphicsView stretch scene to fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942581/qt-graphicsview-stretch-scene-to-fit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

scaling the view like bellow doing what required:

```
view->scale(frameWidth / sceneWidth, frameHeight / sceneHeight);
```

Comment: How can I get frameWidth/sceneWidth/ etc?

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
void MyGraphicsView::zoomToFit()
{
    fitInView(scene()->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
}
```

You might want to [adjust](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qrect.html#adjusted) the scene rectangle to have a little margin; might look better, depending on your content.

Answer (score 4):

```
view->setSceneRect(0, 0, view->frameSize().width(), view->frameSize().height());
```

Connect this piece of code with `resizeEvent` of `QGraphicsView`

If you set scene rect with size greater than view's, scroll bars will appear. Else if you set scene rect equal to view's frame width or less, no scroll bars will be there.

Then I guess [`QGraphicsView::fitInView()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView) is your solution.

Comment: It Will just reset sceneRect, i.e. it will crop extra part which is  out side of this rect, but didnt shrink it

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer the question, but this is at the top of google when searching for how to fit the contents to the view.  It's simply:

```
def fit_contents(self):
    items = self.scene().items()
    rects = [item.mapToScene(item.boundingRect()).boundingRect() for item in items]
    rect = min_bounding_rect(rects)
    self.setSceneRect(rect)
```

Where min_bounding_rect is:

```
def min_bounding_rect(rectList):
if rectList == []:
    return None

minX = rectList[0].left()
minY = rectList[0].top()
maxX = rectList[0].right()
maxY = rectList[0].bottom()

for k in range(1, len(rectList)):
    minX = min(minX, rectList[k].left())
    minY = min(minY, rectList[k].top())
    maxX = max(maxX, rectList[k].right())
    maxY = max(maxY, rectList[k].bottom())

return QRectF(minX, minY, maxX-minX, maxY-minY)
```